# Puede haber varias relaciones ligadas a la misma entidad/tabla

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Estoy trabajando en laravel con postgesql y quiero enlazar dos tablas intermedias:

Tengo la tabla **Usuarios** y la tabla **Tema**

[image: modelo entidad relación]

¿Es correcto que existan más de una relación de muchos a muchos entre dos tablas (en este caso entre Usuario y Tema)?

Quiero implementar esto en laravel. Según la documentación las tablas pivote se crean uniendo el nombre de las dos tablas, entonces quedaría `php artisan make:migration create_theme_user_table` pero solo puedo hacer esto una vez pero necesito hacerlo dos veces. ¿Hay alguna manera de poder hacer esto?

Comment: No termino de entender la duda, por ejemplo si esta relacionada a dudas de como crear esto desde Laravel o si es a nivel de sql, es decir una duda de diseño, por favor lee [ask], edita y explica mejor

Comment: Lo quiero crear desde laravel y como motor de base de datos es postgresql.

Comment: Si, pero entonces cual es la duda, ¿preguntas si es válido lo que planeas? o ¿preguntas cómo hacerlo por que no sabes desde Laravel?

Comment: No se como hacerlo desde Laravel

Comment: La doc. oficial a parte de ser muy fácil es un excelente punto de partida, [aqui puedes ver como se hace](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations), trata algo y si tienes dudas en el proceso te podemos entonces auxiliar con gusto

Comment: Sigo con dudas :c

Comment: Tienes que empezar con algo... tus dudas se iran aclarando con el avance, aunque te equivoques puedes volver a consultarlo. Empieza creando una base de datos de prueba con las tablas como las mencionas. Si fallas en algo, lo notaras, lo resuelves y si no lo resuelves, pides ayuda. Animo !!!

Comment: Si la idea es diferenciar entre los temas que vista y consulta, puedes crear el archivo de migración y duplica para tema tanto la columna como la llave foránea y nombrando por ejemplo `id_tema_visita` y `id_tema_comenta`. Otra alternativa es en lugar de duplicar la columna, sería agregar un columna `tipo` que almacene valores como `V` para visita y `C` para consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Si generas la migración para una tabla intermedia (con artisan o a mano) simplemente copia el archivo y edita el nombre de la clase, tabla e índices según corresponda. La migración para visitas sería algo como:

```
class CreateVisitaTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('visita', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id', true);
            $table->integer('id_usuario')->index('id_usuario_visita');
            $table->integer('id_theme')->index('id_theme_visita');
            $table->nullableTimestamps();
            
            $table->foreign('id_usuario', 'visita_usuario')->references('id')
                        ->on('usuario')->onUpdate('CASCADE')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreign('id_theme', 'visita_theme')->references('id')
                        ->on('theme')->onUpdate('CASCADE')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('visita');
    }
}
```

Y la de comentarios sería más o menos igual pero imagino que corresponde ponerle un campo de tipo `text` con el contenido del comentario.

Lo importante es que no estás limitado a lo que te ofrezca artisan para ahorrarte trabajo, que son convenciones y no limitaciones.